# Is it possible to keep application priorities same even after restart in Windows-10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, task-manager

I usually change priorities of few application which I'm not using to low when I'm using applications which consume a lot of CPU and RAM. I also set their priorities to `realtime` using Task Manager.

But I have to change their properties to low after each and every time I restart my Desktop.
Is there any way so that `Windows 10` remembers the priorities that I had assigned?

And yes some of the applications whose priority I set to 'low' are namely `DWM`, `SearchIndexer` and a few `svchosts`.

Comment: Process Hacker will allow you to do that between restarts. Not sure about real-time, but any application you set to run with elevated priority will run the same way after reboot.

Comment: @Didier I won't mind settings priority to realtime because I set priority to realtime only when I am using it. I want to set priorities to LOW and want them to remain LOW even after reboot. Will Process Hacker save the low priority state/

Comment: Yes it does. That's the big difference with Process Explorer (which is a fine piece of software too): you right-click on a process, set the priority the way you want (even idle if you want to), then right-click again and choose "save for...", and it's done.

Comment: @Didier sorry for late response.  I was unable to find a fair version of Process Hacker. Every time I download from multiple sites, my Anti-virus quarantines the setup as it contains some virus.

Comment: It's a false positive, as Process Hacker installs a kernel driver that allows it to stop, restart, or even delete services, which can come in handy in the case of recalcitrant drivers. See here for more explanations (https://wj32.org/processhacker/forums/viewtopic.php?t=2925), and here (https://www.crowdstrike.com/blog/doppelpaymer-ransomware-and-dridex-2/ ; about midway down the page) to understand why PH can be deadly when it falls into the wrong hands. Use at your discretion. I've been a user for several years, and I still live to tell the tale...

Comment: @Didier I'll have a read at  that...

Comment: Yes, it's best to make your own opinion on such things. Up to you, really. Let us know how it went.